# Rename and remove function for the txt file is not working c++

Tags: c++

I know this is asked a lot, but I am spending hours to solve this problem. I am trying to edit txt file by replacing names. I copied my datas to the temp.txt file and when I enter the inputs, temp file does the job and changing the word. But the functions which are remove and rename are not working. My code is below:

```
string search_string;

    string replace_string;

   ofstream file;

    file.open("temp.txt"); //opening file

    cout<<"Enter the word you want to change: ";

    cin>>search_string;

    cout<<"Enter the new word: ";

    cin>>replace_string;

    string inbuf;

    fstream input_file("musics.txt", ios::in);

    ofstream output_file("temp.txt");

  while (!input_file.eof())
  {
      getline(input_file, inbuf);

      int spot = inbuf.find(search_string);

 if(spot >= 0)
      {
    'this is the replacing part' 
      }  
     output_file << inbuf << endl;

    remove("musics.txt");

    file.close();

    rename("temp.txt", "musics.txt");
}
```

Comment: Picture a file as an array.  You can only replace in the file if the entries are the same size (length).  Deleting text does not remove it (like an array).  You should backup the original and write the edited text to a new file.

Comment: Read your program again. Try to figure out why do you need two, not one, but two `std::ofstream` objects, when you expect to write only one output file. Once you figure out the answer to this question, you will be able to figure out your own bug. This is not the only bug in the shown code, but once you fix this one, you'll be able to work on the next one.

Comment: This is for my university project, you are absolutely right about finding it on my own but I have limited time, so can you tell me how to fix them please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main problems.

- You open the output file twice.
- You must close all files before you do file operations

Especially the 2nd topic is causing the trouble.

Here a working solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

// The filenames
const std::string musicFileName{ "music.txt" };
const std::string tempFileName{ "temp.txt" };


int main() {

    // Open a new scope, so that the file streams 
    // will be closed automatically by the destructor
    {
        // Open the source file
        std::ifstream sourceFile(musicFileName);

        // Check, if it could be opened
        if (sourceFile) {

            // Source file is open, now open the temp file
            std::ofstream tempFile(tempFileName);

            // Check, if the tempfile could be opened
            if (tempFile) {

                // Both files are open, get the search and replace strings
                std::string searchString;
                std::string replaceString;

                std::cout << "Enter the word you want to change: ";
                std::cin >> searchString;

                std::cout << "Enter the new word: ";
                std::cin >> replaceString;

                // Now read all lines from source file
                std::string textLine{};
                while (std::getline(sourceFile, textLine)) {

                    // Replace the text and write it to the destination file
                    tempFile << std::regex_replace(textLine, std::regex(searchString), replaceString) << "\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Could not open '" << tempFileName << "'\n";
            }
        }  //  <-- This will close the temp file
        else {
            std::cerr << "Could not open '" << musicFileName << "'\n";
        }
    }  //  <-- This will close the source file

    // Remove and rename
    std::remove(musicFileName.c_str());
    std::rename(tempFileName.c_str(), musicFileName.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```